# Vertical Scroller in android phonegap

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

I have a dynamic list coming in phonegap. How to add a vertical scroller to that simple `ul`, `li` list?

I have tried using `overflow:auto` to the `div`, but the scroller is not working though it is visible.

I dont want to use `iscroll` plugin. Any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a 2.x device, `overflow:scroll` (or `auto`) simply won't work, that is a known quirk. Same problem applied to iframes btw.

For those devices you have no choice but to use a javascript scroller, if you don't want to use iScroll, there is plenty of other options:

- [FTscroller](https://github.com/ftlabs/ftscroller)
- [Overthrow](https://filamentgroup.github.io/Overthrow/)
- [Intel App Framework 2.2 Scroller Component](https://github.com/01org/appframework/blob/2.2/plugins/af.scroller.js) ([Documentation](https://github.com/01org/appframework/blob/2.2/documentation/plugins/scroller.md))